# Does OLA Scripts support striping for backup to URL?

Tags: ola-hallengren

I am testing backups to blob using OLA scripts. However, I am unable to stripe the backups into multiple files. I tried using 'Numberoffiles' parameter. 
Please advise.

I am using a shared access signature to backup to URL and below is the command:
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'DBA', @URL = https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbabackups',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Compress = 'Y',@Numberoffiles=10

Best Regards,
Sharath

Comment: Can you please edit the post and add the exact command you are issuing? And your expectation for the backup result too.

Comment: What version of Ola's scripts are you using? Support for striping to blob storage was only added in March 2018 (https://ola.hallengren.com/versions.html) so if you're on an older version it won't work.

Comment: Yes, it does support. I had to recreate the credentials. Thanks for your responses!This thread can be closed.